# Is possible to toggle between 2 FontAwesome 5 icons (regular and solid) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I was trying to toggle two classes simultaneously one `fas` and `far` and another border-heart and selected heart. The code results in the display of another solid heart along with the regular one.

```js
var w=1


 $('.heart').on('click',function() {
    if(w == 1) {
    $('.heart').removeClass('far fa-heart').addClass('fas fa-heart');
    $('.heart').removeClass('border-heart').addClass('selected-heart');
       }
   else {
    $('.heart').removeClass('fas fa-heart').addClass('far fa-heart');
    $('.heart').removeClass('selected-heart').addClass('border-heart');
       }
    w=1-w; 
    
});
/*I want to toggle the regular heart icon with solid on click and increase its size by 1 px using selected-heart class and removing border-heart*/
```

```css
.border-heart{
 color: red;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.selected-heart{
 color: red;
 font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heart"><i class="far fa-heart border-heart"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to target the `<i>` within `.heart` using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)... Then simply use the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method on both `.far` and `.fas` classes (and the 2 custom classes you have for font-size change).

;)

```js
$('.heart').on('click',function() {
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("far fas selected-heart border-heart");
});
```

```css
.border-heart{
  color: red;
  font-size: 21px;
}
.selected-heart{
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heart"><i class="far fa-heart border-heart"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a quick fix. It looks like you're trying to toggle between two classes, however, you have selected the parent of the item you actually want. You are selecting the `.heart` div, but you actually want to be selecting the `i` element within. You should modify your jquery to the following;

```
var w=1


$('.heart').on('click',function() {
    if(w == 1) {
        //standard CSS selector selecting the child i element from the .heart element
        $('.heart i').removeClass('fas fa-heart').addClass('fa fa-heart');
    }
    else {
        $('.heart i').removeClass('fa fa-heart').addClass('fas fa-heart');
    }
    w=w-1;  
});
```

Comment: there is one another problem

Comment: eg. <div class="1"><div class="heart"><i class="far fa-heart border-heart"></i></div></div><div class="2"><div class="heart"><i class="far fa-heart border-heart"></i></div></div>                                                                                                     how to make sure that it will target the icon in specific div and not all the divs?